# erase hardware-encrypted SSD

Tags: encryption, ssd, disk-encryption, samsung

### Disclaimer

I'm not robbing someone, didn't rob someone in the past and don't plan to do so anytime soon.

### Situation

Imagine I own a Samsung 2.5" SSD (850, 860 or the like) which is encrypted.
If it's a software encryption like Bitlocker, FileVault or VeraCrypt, I can simply reformat the disk and should be fine. But these Samsung SSDs also come with a AES-256Bit hardware encryption and I don't know the PW. **I'm not interested in the data that might be on the disk (or not).**

### Question

How do I erase the hardware-encrypted disk without having the PW? My only goal is to repurpose the SSD, not getting access to the data itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you don't want to decrypt the disk, you want to make it usable.

Linux:

- Install sedutil and follow this guide: https://superuser.com/a/1769237

Windows:

- Put this drive into a Windows PC
- Install Samsung Magician
- Disable HW encryption.